# using loadUrl()

Tags: android

It's been a few years since I've tried to create an Android application and since everything has moved away from Eclipse and now onto AS my old templates no longer work. I'm looking for tutorials that allow me to use my own custom html, css and Jquery, seeing as stuff like `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");` don't seem to work anymore.

Are there any links or anything anyone can provide to get me started on creating non java dependant application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make an app without using java you can start learning ionic framework https://ionicframework.com/
You can also go through Apache Cordova. It allows you to use standard web technologies such as HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development and you can also go with Xamarin that uses C# for cross-platform development.

You can also go through this tutorial for better understanding and for start learning from fresh :
**Ionic tutorial** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jamhGf-8ww&list=PLYxzS__5yYQljbuGjaeugpqs9U07gS5P5

**Cordova Tutorial** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqWZuEpHoSw&list=PLReL099Y5nRd9BNsMZwXvTDeqnfRMiGJy

Hope this will be helpful!!

Comment: Is there Cordova tutorial using Android Studio? Visual has been causing me issues for a while now, I can barely get it to open

Comment: No, but you can use command line tools and NodeJs, NPM Here is the link to get you started: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/ ... But visual is referred because it is easy and more convenient to use.